# Custom excel date

Tags: excel

I’m a newbie here after being promoted to an office role after being a service Engineer,
What I wish to achieve is a self-populating cell as below 
Sun 2 Mar to Sat 8 Mar 2014 
The next cell would read 
Sun 9 Mar to Sat 15 Mar 2014
If anyone can help I be so great full
How do I input self-learning in to excel 
Many thanks to all that view & help

Comment: can you, please, give a more detailed explanation of your problem (and also would be great to add any example), because I can't understand anything from your question.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question and what you're exactly looking for. Usually, automatic behaviour is obtained from scripting in VBA and not usual formulas...

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*(ROW()-1),"ddd d mmm") &  " to " & TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*ROW()-1,"ddd d mmm yyyy")
```

and copy down

Comment: 0

down vote

accept
 

Hi all and thank you for your interest and help,

Gary thank you 

The formula that Gary has designed gives me almost what I need the only small modification if possible is if the formula could be modified to go horizontally rather then vertically as show below

=TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*(ROW()-1),"ddd d mmm") & " to " & TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*ROW()-1,"ddd d mmm yyyy")

Sun 2 Mar to Sat 8 Mar 2014

Sun 9 Mar to Sat 15 Mar 2014

Sun 16 Mar to Sat 22 Mar 2014

Sun 23 Mar to Sat 29 Mar 2014



Once again thank you for your warm support kind regards Simon

Answer (score 0):

This formula can be copied horizontally:

```
=TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*(COLUMN()-1),"ddd d mmm") &  " to " & TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*COLUMN()-1,"ddd d mmm yyyy")
```

**EDIT #1**:

This formula has the time as well:

```
="8 am " & TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*(COLUMN()-1),"ddd d mmm") &  " to 8 am " & TEXT(DATE(2014,3,2)+7*COLUMN()-1,"ddd d mmm yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you Gary,   I did try to edit the formula by writing COL then from the drop down list I picked COLUML  I don't know why it didn't work for me but thanks I can now experiment b adding a fixed time eg 08-00hr Sun 23 Mar to 08-00hr Sat 29 Mar 2014, then I will look into more cell populations eg if I enter a name the next cell self populates a phone number Once again many thanks Kind regards Simon

Comment: Great! ............... Update this Post if you need more help!

Comment: Hi, I been trying to edit the formula(s) to add times however am having no no success, Would it be possible for you to edit the formula to show:- 8am Fri 27 Dec to 8am Fri 3 Jan 2014 Many thanks in advance simon

Comment: Give me an hour........................

Comment: See **EDIT#1** ......................

Comment: Oh I see how you done it as a”text”,
I was trying to input a calculation,
Ok thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction 
Many thanks 
Si

Comment: In your case, the Text approach is much more simple.